# Prove a function over Borel probability space is discontinuous

Tags: probability, measure-theory

### Setting

Suppose $Q\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a compact metric space. Let $\mathcal{P}(Q)$ be the set of Borel probability measures on $Q$. This set is endowed with the topology of weak-* convergence: a sequence $\left\{ m_{N} \right\}$ of $\mathcal{P}(Q)$ converges to $m \in \mathcal{P}(Q)$ if $\forall \varphi \in C(Q)$
$$
\lim _N \int_Q \varphi(x) d m_N(x)=\int_Q \varphi(x) d m(x)  ,
$$

which can be metrized by the distance
$$
\mathbf{d}_1(\mu, \nu)=\sup \left\{\int _{Q}   fd\left(\mu -\nu\right) : \operatorname{Lip}\left(f;Q\right)\leq  1\right\},
$$ where $\operatorname{Lip}\left(f;Q\right)$ denotes the minimal Lipschitz constant of $f$. The equivalent distance is given by
$$
d_1(\mu, \nu)=\inf _{M\in\Pi(\mu, \nu)} \int_{Q \times Q} d(x, y) \,d M(x, y),
$$
where $\Pi (\mu,\nu)$ is all couplings of $\mu$ and $\nu$, i.e.
$$
M\left(A\times Q\right)=\mu\left(A\right),\,M\left(Q\times A\right)=\nu\left(A\right) \quad\forall A \in \mathscr{B}\left(Q\right).
$$

### Question

I'm reading a Pierre Cardaliaguet's MFG note about the limit of sequence of symmetric functions. The author says that the function
$$
U\left(m\right)=\sup_{y \in \operatorname{Spt}\left(m\right)}\left| y \right|:\mathcal{P}\left(Q\right)\to \mathbb{R}
$$
is not continuous. Here $\operatorname{Spt}(m)$ denotes the support of $m$, which is defined by
$$
\operatorname{Spt}(m):=\left\{x \in Q \mid \forall N_x\in \mathcal{O}_{x}:\left(x \in N_x \Rightarrow \mu\left(N_x\right)>0\right)\right\}.
$$
But I have no idea proving it. Can someone give me some glues? Thanks so much!

Comment: What does $|y|$ mean in a metric space?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Sorry, I forget to say $Q\subset\mathbb{R}$ and the modulus is just the absolute value. I will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Q$ have at least two distinct points, say $x_1,x_2\in Q$ with $\vert x_1\vert <\vert x_2\vert$ (if all points on $Q$ have the same absolute value, then $U$ is constant and therefore continuous). Then define $$m_n=\frac{n-1}{n}\delta_{x_1} +\frac{1}{n} \delta_{x_2}.$$
For $\varphi\in C(Q)$ we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_Q \varphi(x)dm_n(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left( \frac{n-1}{n} \varphi(x_1)+\frac{1}{n} \varphi(x_2)\right)
=\int_Q \varphi(x) \delta_{x_1}(x).$$ Hence, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} m_n=\delta_{x_1}$ in $\mathcal{P}(Q)$. However, $U(m_n)=\vert x_2\vert$ and thus
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} U(m_n)=\vert x_2\vert \neq \vert x_1\vert =U(\delta_{x_1}).$$
As continuity would imply sequential continuity, we get that $U$ is discontinuous.